# Windowsの電卓の内部変数の型について

Tags: windows

Windowsの電卓ですが、Double型とDecimal型のいいとこ取りといいますか、両方の特徴を有しています。
具体的には、
Ａ． 0.1+0.1+0.1・・・と加算をしていくと、Double型では誤差が出て0.3じゃなくなり、Decimalはちゃんと0.3、というようなことになります。
しかし電卓ではちゃんと0.3なり0.9となります。

Ｂ． 1 / 3 * 3 を順に計算すると、Double型では1.0となり、Decimalだと0.9999999999999となってしまいます。
しかし電卓ではちゃんと 1 になります。途中、1/3の時点で0.33333333333となってしまうにも関わらず、です。

このように、電卓はいたって普通の計算結果ではあるのですが、言語の型ではいいとこ取りに見えます。
どのような処理をしているのでしょうか？

Comment: Windows10付属の電卓の精度は仮数部32桁、指数部が10^-9999～10^9999です。いずれもDoubleやDecimalでは表現できませんので明らかに独自の型を使用しています。

Comment: [The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040525-00/?p=39193/)に "The standard IEEE floating point library was replaced with an arbitrary-precision arithmetic library" なんて記述がありますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
質問のA.の方のように、一旦出るdouble特有の誤差の後に、しれっと誤差がなかったように見えるのが意味わからないところだったのですが、昔からの問題であってIEEEで定義されるような仕様だったのですね。

Answer (score 5):

[When you change the insides, nobody notices | The Old New Thing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040525-00/?p=39193/) によると、元々IEEE標準の浮動小数点数演算に準拠していたのが、四則演算に限り任意精度演算が行えるように書き直されたようです。具体的な時期は書かれていませんが、手元の98SEでもそれらしい挙動が確認できました。

当時は本当に値域に制限がなかったらしく、どこまで `n!` を計算できるか、なんてスレッドまで。

[What's the highest number you can put in the Windows calculator - AnandTech Forums](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?s=64c38dcc774dd858651f4beb8b98fbbf&t=137344)

ただ、上記スレの最後のページにもあるように、Win7からは 10^9999 あたりを超えたところで「オーバーフローしました」と表示されるようになっていますね。

[What is the largest number that can be use use in window 7 calculator - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/what-is-the-largest-number-that-can-be-use-use-in/dc54ec50-22b9-44db-a284-38cc8f6da1b2?auth=1)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excelも1/3*3が1となります。Excelでの挙動については「[Excel で浮動小数点演算の結果が正しくない場合がある](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/kb/78113)」に記載があります。おそらくは同じような実装になっているのでしょう。